# How to match the exact string with multiple URL using regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am using caching and i store user_id with cached the page,When the user is logged out,I need to clear the cache for specific user's cached page using user_id.I used following regex for deleting the matched user_id

```
cache_store.delete_matched("*id=#{current_user.id}*")
```

It deletes all the URL when it matches with first number,for example it deletes all the URL if i want to delete the id=12.

```
"localhost:3000/foo?id=123"
"localhost:3000/foo?id=12"
"localhost:3000/foo?id=129"
```

I want to delete the URL which has id=12.Help me to solve this.

Comment: is there anything after the 12? ie ?id=12/bar or is the id always the last value?  if always last value, remove the asterix. if there is something else you will need to check for that something something else

Comment: Could you please give 2 or more `URL`s for instance? and also mention there what portion you want to extract for each URL.

Comment: localhost:3000/foo/objects.text/html?id=94"     localhost:3000/foo/objects.text/javascript?id=94&search=52" localhost:3000/foo/objects.text/javascript?id=94&search=521" localhost:3000/foo/objects/page/1.text/javascript?id=94" localhost:3000/foo?id=941                                            localhost:3000/foo?id=943 It clears all the Urls when i use above mentioned regex.

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly. Your case should be covered by the given `regex`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the userid cannot be followed by any digit.

```
cache_store.delete_matched("id=#{current_user.id}([\D]|$)")
```

This matches an `URL` ending with the userid, or containing the userid followed by anything but a digit.

**Edit**

Couldn't find a `Share`-button on Regexpal, so I posted my result. Note that I've copied my `regex` string and replaced `#{current_user.id}` with `94`. Both blue and yellow are matches. Seems like only the right lines from your example are matches, no?

[image]

**Edit 2**

Since OP still hasn't been able to successfully remove multiple `URL`s, another update. I suspect there's some fault in the surrounding code. This sample is working:

```
id = 94
array = [ "id=94", "id=94a", "id=945" ]
clean = Array.new
regex = Regexp.new('id=' + id.to_s + '([\D]|$)')

for url in array
    if url =~ regex
        clean << url
    end
end

puts clean
```

In case this still doesn't solve your problem, consider posting the relevant function which is responsible for the removal of `URL`s. Also provide the container for these `URL`s please.

Comment: No it doesn't match and delete the URL ending with the user_id and the user_id followed by anything.

Comment: @Mano, I have clarified my answer. I'm positive that either my answer is sufficient, or something in the question is not clear for me.

Comment: Yes it matches to all URLs which has id=94,Even i checked the regex on regexpal.I used the regex `cache_store.delete_matched("id=#{current_user.id}([^\d]|$)")`Still I am finding where i mistake.`

Comment: In that case I'm guessing the root of your problem is elsewhere. I have posted another edit to my answer.

Comment: Shall i use double quotes when i use regex,because i use variable inside the regex,i guess that would be the problem here.

Comment: I don't know how Ruby handles this, you could use [concatenation](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_String_Concatenation_and_Comparison) to be sure: `"id=" + #{current_user.id} + "([^\d]|$)"`. To be completely sure, you could use `puts` to print the result before using it in `delete_matched()`.

Comment: @Mano: I have taken some time to learn the very basics of `Ruby`. I have created a working sample which you can see in my second edit. This in combination with concatenation should make you able to get the matches you're searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Try `cache_store.delete_matched("id=#{current_user.id}")`